# Emulator appearing offline on M1 Mac after the last update of arm64-v8a

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, apple-m1, avd-manager

Yesterday the emulator was working perfectly. The system image was arm64-v8a. I don't exactly remember the Release name of the working system image but, yesterday there was an update for the ARM 64 system image which I accepted and the release name is "S".

I can start the emulator from my AVD Manager, the emulator also starts when I press the 'Run app' button however, the app isn't loaded on the emulator and the emulator appears offline if I check through "adb devices" or if I click on "Troubleshoot Device connections" it shows:

"emulator-5554 - Device is currently in the offline state"

I have tried most of the suggestions found on StackOverflow like:

- adb kill-server, adb start-server
- Remove and re-create AVD device
- Invalidate Caches/Restart
- Enable USB debugging inside the emulator
- Wipe data and cold boot from AVD manager

  I am using **Android Studio 4.1.3**

  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119, built on March 10, 2021
  Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495 x86_64
  VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
  macOS 10.16
  GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
  Memory: 1981M
  Cores: 8
  Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
  Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin

AVD:

```
Name: Pixel_4_API_S
CPU/ABI: Google Play ARM (arm64-v8a)
Path: ~/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_S.avd
Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level S)
Skin: pixel_4
SD Card: 512M
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: pixel_4
hw.lcd.width: 1080
image.androidVersion.codename: S
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 29
tag.id: google_apis_playstore
hw.mainKeys: no
hw.camera.front: emulated
avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 4 API S
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.ramSize: 1536
PlayStore.enabled: true
fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
hw.cpu.ncore: 4
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
hw.dPad: no
hw.lcd.height: 2280
vm.heapSize: 256
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-S/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a/
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: virtualscene
AvdId: Pixel_4_API_S
hw.lcd.density: 440
hw.arc: false
hw.device.hash2: MD5:6b5943207fe196d842659d2e43022e20
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google Play
runtime.network.latency: none
disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Any idea what has gone wrong? Or how to tackle this issue?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem after setting up my M1 MBA. Also running Android Studio v 4.1.3

Comment: Another poster having the same problem as us - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67250716/getting-device-emulator-5554-is-offline

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Replace the avd system images you have downloaded with the r02 images. r03 is broken for me but reverting to r02 saved the day!

*Update*: It appears r03, r04, and r05 all don't work on m1

[Google Play ARM 64 v8a System Image (revision: 2)](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a-S_r02-darwin.zip)

[Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image (revision: 2)](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/arm64-v8a-S_r02.zip)

With the latest android (4.1.3) on macOS, the directory you want to put the unzipped images in is probably something like `~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-S`.

For example, the path for the google play image is `~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-S/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a`

Comment: How did you find the older images?

Comment: @Daniel - I just looked at the URLs that android studio was using to download the latest versions and tried rolling the revision number back to check if the old images existed at the URLs. current image was `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a-S_r03-darwin.zip` so I just tested rolling that `r03` to `r02` in the URL.

Comment: Solved the problem. Thank you!
However if anyone else needs this, my path to arm64-v8a was: 
/Users/$user_name/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-S/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a

Comment: r04 is broken as well.

Comment: You cannot even imagine how you helped me. Thank you a lot. Really, thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: The answer in the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907154/android-studio-emulator-on-macos-with-arm-cpu-m1 solves the issue.

Don't use the S variant when you're using the Artic Fox 2020.3.1 Android Studio Preview. Use the R variant and the emulator works fine

Comment: @Zane: for those of us ensuring that our software works with S using R doesn't solve our problem

Comment: @AndrewPK Meanwhile revision 5 is available, did you try that one?

Comment: @AndrewPK ah. thats fair. Did not think about that.

I tested revision 5 and it still shows up as offline.

Comment: @AndrewPK can confirm that on 2020.3.1 Beta 4 with Android Emulator 30.7.4 and the arm64-v8a-S-r05 + Pixel 4 XL Device, it no longer shows up as offline

Comment: Thanks very much.

Mine was in: /Users/$user_name/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-S/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a for the Play Store device and /Users/$user_name/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-S/google_apis/arm64-v8a for non Play Store

Comment: so far, this is the only solution that actually worked directly from Android Studio and not using the preview emulator.

Comment: So revisions 3, 4 and 5 don't work?
Thanks a lot for the link for downgrading :)

Comment: Thank you! This was really confusing 

Comment: r06 is broken as well.

Comment: Wow, it's really working! Been messing around with the M1 configuration for Flutter development for 3 days now (in the meantime Arctic Fox got released as stable) and couldn't solve the offline emulator state. Replacing the image with r02 solved the problem and can use the emulator again. Thanks a lot, I owe you like bag of monies for that.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Really, thank you from the deep of my heart

Comment: THIS WORKED AS OF 11/09/2021 on M1 Mac

Comment: Work on 21/09/2021 on m1 mac! the only solution that work for me.. thanks !

Comment: When are they going to fix this?

Comment: Is it just me or is API 31 r8 broken as well? Does not work on my M1.

Comment: @BartekPacia api31 r8 worked for me on mac m1

Comment: upto latest release 9 is broken on Windows for Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image

Answer (score 11):

If you are not use API level S, you can try this: (My API level is 31)

1. Download from [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a-S_r02-darwin.zip)
2. Create a new folder as shown below, unzip the downloaded file and place it inside the new folder
   [image]
   Path: `/Users/<Username>/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-S/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a`
3. Launch Android Studio and click Configure > AVD Manager
4. Click Create Virtual Device ..., select any device, press the Next button and confirm that API level S has been added.
5. Add it to your devices and verify it works with VSCode.
   [image]

Comment: Great thanks for this! Do they even bother to QA at Google Android I wounder sometimes.

Comment: -> 8/02/2023

M1 Apple - This is most viable solution of all the ones I found on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue, not sure if you get it fixed, but I came accross this post when looking for solutions and the above solution didn't work for me.

A solution I did find out about was to install [android-emulator-m1-preview from google](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases/tag/0.3), launch that instead of launching the emulator from inside Android Studio. Its almost annoying how simple of an issue it turned out to be to fix.

Seeing build successful after 12+ hours of trying different solutions is really nice.

Comment: The preview emulator worked well enough for quite some time, but with recent macOS Versions I've experienced network issues with it. Switching to the r02 API helped.

Answer (score 1):

For mac M1 users, just delete the emulator and add another emulator. API level 30 worked for me

Comment: I've tried and deleted like dozen emulators.  Nothing works.  If you are on a Mac, you need the M1 compatible ARM images: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview