# Getting Device emulator-5554 is offline

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

Cannot run Android app on flutter. Getting Device emulator-5554 is offline. I'm thinking it could be and emulator issue since I'm on M1 but it worked 2 days ago and after a flutter upgrade everything stopped.

1. Killing adb
2. Deleting emulator
3. Cold booting Emulator
4. Wiping Emulator
5. Other answers in questions don't work

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.2.0-10.1.pre, on macOS 11.2.1 20D74 darwin-arm,
    locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    ! Device emulator-5554 is offline.
```

Comment: Does  adb device have a result?

Comment: @Anna Gives `List of devices attached
emulator-5554 offline`

Comment: Try  to run "adb kill-server" first , then run "adb devices"  in the cmd . Did try a real phone?

Comment: Does not work. Using emulator

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Real phone works great. Emulator preview for m1 is stated as being outdated/unnecessary with the latest Android Studio. I've tried enabling/disabling USB debugging on the emulator, reseting data, cold booting, killing adb numerous times, etc., and nothing seems to work. An oddity I've spotted is that `AndroidWifi` reports "connected to device. can't provide internet." Update: AndroidWifi is randomly working now after the emulator device crashed and rebooted.