# Android Studio Bumblebee emulator not updating my changes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, apple-m1

I am using macbook with M1 chip. I am using Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 3 version. When I run the project for the first time, there is no problem. When I debug for the second time, the changes I made in the codes are not visible in the emulator. I can't see the changes in logcat. What should I do?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can try to go from **File** to **Invalidate Caches / Restart...** to empty your cache.
2. If that doesn't work try to downgrade your version. M1 Chip has problems with Android Studio because it is pretty new. Follow along this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230200/emulator-appearing-offline-on-m1-mac-after-the-last-update-of-arm64-v8a).

Comment: Nice, did the first or second point work? Feel free to tick the hook to show others it helped you and confirm the correctness of the answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem.
"Edit Configurations..." -> Then the option I have shown in the red square needs to be selected.

[image]

Comment: For me, this didn't make a difference. However, when I switched "Deploy: Default APK" to "Deploy: APK from App Bundle" it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it gets compiled and Android Studio installs it without errors you could try these things that worked for me:

1. Uninstalling the app inside the emulator and then running it again so the app gets reinstalled with your new version.
2. Also, as it's answered on [here](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/683717). You could also go to **Tools -> AVD Manager**. Right click on the emulator and then **wipe data**. This will delate all the data on the device.

[image]