# Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Canary 4 Emulator not working on m1

Tags: android, apple-m1, silicon

So earlier today , I was working on Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020 1.1.3 beta 3 , and decided to upgrade to latest version and therefore install this new version. After installing the new version, emulator did work on my m1 mba for first time but then suddenly stopped working. When I build  my project and run it, it shows "waiting for devices to come online" and the process named qemu-system-aarch64 in my activity monitor but emulator doesnt show up in android studio or in any separate window.
Weird thing that now even android-emulator-m1-preview doesnt work now after upgrading to this bumblebee version.Earlier it was working, but now its not.
Things I tried:

1. Downgrading to Arctic Fox RC version.
2. Downgrading to the previous version where emulator was working but no luck.
3. Deleting Android folder in Users\user\Library
4. Resetting IDE preferences.
5. Wiping Data and cold reboot.
6. Installing arm64-v8a-S_r02-darwin.zip as suggested in [Emulator appearing offline on M1 Mac after the last update of arm64-v8a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230200/emulator-appearing-offline-on-m1-mac-after-the-last-update-of-arm64-v8a)
7. Reinstalling android emulator.

Comment: Same for me with Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8092744 on a Mac mini (M1, 2020) with macOS 11.6.

Comment: I have just figured out that the emulator is not working as long as "Launch in a tool window" (Preferences / Tools / Emulator) is activated. As soon as I deactivate this setting, the emulator begins to start working again. This is by no means a solution to this problem but maybe a workaround for some people.

Comment: I have been struggling with the same problem. However all was fine, even after upgrading to Bumblebee, until I added a new emulator... Only fix for me was to follow advice by @PhilippFahlteich, and to use the emulator as an external app. It worked great as an internal process beforehand, but now I have no option.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Bumblebee and it won't be fixed soon as this has a long, long history not only on M1. The workaround of running the emulator as external app "works" because the system gets a chance to kill the app when it doesn't quit on quit. And you get to fill out a bug report to Apple each and every time if you want. Wouldn't call that "working".
Emulators launched inside AS Bumblebee on M1 become rogue processes right away (red in Activity Monitor where you can also kill them). This was an issue in the original Arctic Fox installs and took a ton of releases to be fixed in 2020.3.1 Patch 4. Now we are restarting the cycle. There are tons of reports, but Google is sort of ignoring it. It's macOS/Apple after all, so no - great - hurry.
This is an issue that would have come up right away if any testing was done at all with a pristine M1 / Bumblebee install. Just stick to Arctic Fox for now.

Edit: Fix came out today and seems to be working. Fingers crossed. [Feb 3, 2022]

Answer (score 1):

The emulator will work on a stand-alone window.

For Bumblebee stable version, on Mac M1.

Android Studio -> preferences -> Tools -> Emulator -> uncheck "Launch in a tool window".