# Android Studio [BumbleBee 2021.1.1] Emulator Timeout on Mac M1

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I have Android Studio BumbleBee 2021.1.1 downloaded, running on a MacBook Pro M1. When downloading Android Studio, I chose the Apple Chip option (opposed to Intel)

I've created a Virtual Device - Android 12.0 arm64-v8a Pixel 4.

When I attempt to run the emulator it gets stuck here

[image: Connecting to the Emulator...]

Then, it times out:

[image: Timeout Error]

I have searched SO and other blogs and can only find outdated material based on a time in 2020/2021 when Android did not support ARM64. However, it's my understanding that this has now changed so https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview is no longer needed.

What is the correct way to run the Android Emulator on a Mac with an M1 Chip?

Comment: Same problem as in the canary version of Android Studio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68479673/android-studio-bumblebee-2021-1-1-canary-4-emulator-not-working-on-m1

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have found the issue so marking this as solved, however, if anyone knows *why* this solves the problem, please share!

I found an issue opened on Google's anroid-emulator-m1-preview repo with this answer https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/issues/76#issuecomment-1023563846

Turns out, I just needed to uncheck 'Launch in a tool window' but again, not sure why that fixed the issue.

Comment: Working fine only on Emulator  API version 31.

Comment: this is the correct answer

Comment: Atleast in mac it times out- for windows its eternity trying to load emulator. unchecking the option worked for me after a cold boot. Bumblebee version is so unstable, how google ends up labeling it stable is beyond me.