# Android Studio Arctic Fox does not debug on Apple M1

Tags: android, android-studio, apple-m1

Fresh install of Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 with arm64 support.
Reccomended configuration during the first launch, the app downloads and install all the necessary files then is ready.

Opened an old project, updated Gradle to V7, clicked the debug button:
A lot of

```
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.myapp | com.example.myapp.test
```

and then

```
Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.
Timed out waiting for process (com.example.myapp) to appear on Pixel_3a_API_S [emulator-5554].
```

Rebooted, reinstalled the emulator, even tried to downgrade to r02 as suggested here: [Emulator appearing offline on M1 Mac after the last update of arm64-v8a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230200/emulator-appearing-offline-on-m1-mac-after-the-last-update-of-arm64-v8a)

No luck. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a stupid mistake: in order to target Android S I added the `exported` property to my activity in manifest.xml with `false` as value.

Switching to true solved the issue.

First world autocomplete problem.